# Flash AIR game: What Performance To Expect Of Blitting

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, game-engine

I have tried writting my own blit-based 2D side scroller game engine in Flash AS3

Question is: What should be the amount of blitted sprites i can expect on a computer in a 2d side scroller game? I can currently roughly run:

100 gameObject
(ie enemies, player characters, npcs, item drops etc)

or 400 background Object (static image)

In a game, there would definitely be many operations, eg detecting collision with enemies, obstacles etc

What should be the amount of blitted sprites i can expect on a computer in a 2d side scroller game with these operations in mind?

==========

*I currently render from a imageCache Object storing all frames stripped from a test spritesheet I am using (50 frames of a character movement)

- no Hittest involved, all collision is math based

Comment: You probably won't have to blit at all.  If everything is bitmaps, you get most of the performace.  You need to blit when you're getting crazy.  Keep all bitmaps under the device's limit - usually the size of the screen - and you can put tons of stuff on screen and get 60fps.  You must use Scout.

Comment: This question is overly broad and only has opinion based replies. Not a great match for Stackoverflow.